# kivy buttons don't work inside accordion?

Tags: kivy

When I bind a function to a button inside an accordion nothing happens upon clicking it. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. :( Any thoughts?

```
def printTest():
    print "The button worked!"

accord = Accordion(anim_duration=1.5, orientation='vertical')
specialButton = Button(text="click me", font_size='20sp', text_size=(1100, None), halign="center")
specialButton.bind(on_press=printTest():

item = AccordionItem(title="Hello World")
item.add_widget(specialButton)
accord.add_widget(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
specialButton.bind(on_press=printTest():
```

This isn't valid syntax, is the colon a typo?

Either way, the problem is that you are *calling* printTest, not *passing* it as an argument.

Instead try

```
def printTest(*args):
    print "The button worked!"
```

...and...

```
specialButton.bind(on_press=printTest)
```

The `*args` is important because the binding automatically passes some arguments.

I covered this in more detail [here](http://inclem.net/2014/03/11/kivy/kivy_bind_method/).